# why when try upload a large video, app engine gcloud throws error 413 entity too large?

Tags: java, gcloud

I have an API rest with spring boot and with it I upload a video, the question is that when I run it in my local environment, it runs perfect for long videos and actually uploads them to my storage in gcloud, but when I upload to production for this type video throws error 413 entity too large.

any idea why it works locally and not in production

this is the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{videoId}/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST )
public ResponseEntity<Object> uploadTest(@PathVariable Long videoId, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    try {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(uploadVideo(videoId, file));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return processException(e);
    }
}
```

this function is called from controller:

```
public String uploadVideo(MultipartFile fileStream, final String folder, final String bucketName) throws IOException, ServletException {

InputStream resourceAsStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("project.json");

storage = getInstance(resourceAsStream);

        String blobName = fileStream.getName();
        BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(bucketName, blobName);
        byte[] content = fileStream.getBytes();

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("-YYYY-MM-dd-HHmmssSSS");
        DateTime dt = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC);
        String dtString = dt.toString(dtf);
        String extension = fileStream.getOriginalFilename().substring(fileStream.getOriginalFilename().lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        final String fileName = fileStream.getName() + dtString + "." + extension;

        BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(bucketName, folder + "/" + fileName)
                                    .setAcl(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Acl.of(User.ofAllUsers(), Role.READER))))
                                    .build();
        try (WriteChannel writer = storage.writer(blobInfo)) {
            try {
                writer.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(content, 0, content.length));
                return "https://storage.googleapis.com/" + bucketName + "/" + folder  + "/" + fileName;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.toString());
                throw new BadRequestException("Error uploading");
            }
        }
}
```

thank so much, for you help

Comment: App Engine (standard?) limits the request size to 32MB (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Requests). While it's understandable, I think it's not good practice to assume the dev server is a proxy for the production service. I recommend you upload the files directly to Cloud Storage and consider use notifications (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications) to e.g. enqueue metadata of the object, ultimately then triggering your App Engine processing handler.

Comment: @DazWilkin i think that your comment is the right answer for this issue, please move your comment to an answer

Answer (score 1):

App Engine (standard?) limits the request size to 32MB ([link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Requests)).

While it's understandable, I think it's not good practice to assume the dev server is a proxy for the production service.

I recommend you upload the files directly to Cloud Storage and consider use [notifications](http://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications) to e.g. enqueue metadata of the object, ultimately then triggering your App Engine processing handler.